# Adding a keyframe to different object inside of armature animation causes entire object to move

Tags: animation, objects, keyframes

I have an armature animation set up. The armature animation works perfectly smoothly.

I add an object to the scene, and add a location keyframe from this object to the armature animation.

As soon as I play this animation with the new keyframe, literally the entire armature mesh moves INSIDE of the new object I just added.

There is no parenting relationship between the two as far as I can tell-- this happens even immediately after I add a new object.

Am I doing something wrong here? This is completely baffling to me and I don't understand what's happening at all.

In addition, when I press ctrl+z, the weird displacement doesn't fix itself until long after the initial keyframe-adding is reverted. It has to also undo several seemingly unrelated actions before everything is back to normal.

Please help-- I have no clue what's going on.